Why does cupsfilter not use the same filters as cups
I added my own custom filter to cups, to add watermark to every printed page. To do so I added my own script under /usr/lib/cups/filter. Then under /etc/cups/ I added mime.types with:
"application/vnd.cups-pdf" 

and mime.convs with:
"application/vnd.cups-pdf application/vnd.cups-pdf 0 customFilter.sh"

Now from what I understand is, that when cups tries to print a pdf, it looks for a suitable filter to use. It the sees that it can convert a pdf to a pdf with 0 cost and uses my filter.
Now I wanted to see if cups calls any other filters beside mine. So I entered:
cupsfilter -m application/pdf -d brother pdf-test.pdf > test.pdf

On the man page it tells me that the conversion process is the same as cups would use it to print for real, however the output of this command is a pdf page without watermark. Furthermore in the output I can see, that it only uses a flter called gziptoany and nothing else.
When I looked further into it I saw that my printer (Brother HL-L8260CDW), has the lines:
cupsfilter2: "image/jpeg image/jpeg 0 -"

and
cupsfilter2: "image/urf image/urf 100 -",

which I understand to mean, that cups should use a filter that converts to image/jpeg.
Now I am left with a few questions:

Why is my filter even working when I print, when cups should convert to image/jpeg and my filter only converts to pdf?

Why does cupsfilter not reflect this and gives me the original pdf without watermark when, cups itslef clearly uses the filter?


